# Pseudolocalization cannot find English (XA) in languages

Tags: android, pseudolocalization

I am trying to use pseudolocalization as indicated in the official android documentation:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/pseudolocales

I follow each step:

- added `pseudoLocales true` in gradle file under debug buildconfig
- run the app
- go to settings -> languages

but unfortunately I cannot find English (XA). Maybe I am missing something.

Tested on Samsung Galaxy A7

Comment: Have you enabled developer settings?